# Inequality for smallest singular value of product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis

I'm trying to show for $n\times n$ complex matrices $A$ and $B$ that $$s(AB)\geq s(A)s(B)$$
where $s(M)$ is the smallest singular value of $M$.

I've proved this when one of $A$, $B$ is singular (in this case $s(A)s(B)=0$).

I've also proved when one of $A$, $B$ is unitary. Since if B is unitary then $s(B)=1$ and $$B^*A^*AB=s(AB)^2 v \implies A^*A(Bv)=s(AB)^2 Bv$$
so $s(AB)\geq s(A) = s(A)s(B) $. Using $s(M^*)=s(M)$, a similar argument goes when $A$ is unitary.

However, I'm unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to prove this when $A$ and $B$ are invertible (either via a continuity argument or by the direct case considered for singularity by OP).   Making use of submultiplicativity of the operator 2 norm:

$0\lt \Big(\sigma_{\min}\big(AB\big)\Big)^{-1}=\sigma_{\max}\Big(\big(AB\big)^{-1}\Big)=\sigma_{\max}\big(B^{-1}A^{-1}\Big)=\Big \Vert B^{-1}A^{-1}\Big \Vert_2$
$\leq \Big \Vert B^{-1}\Big \Vert_2\big \Vert A^{-1}\Big \Vert_2$
$=\sigma_{\max}\Big(A^{-1}\Big)\cdot \sigma_{max}\Big(B^{-1}\Big)=\Big(\sigma_{\min}\big(A\big)\Big)^{-1}\cdot \Big(\sigma_{\min}\big(B\big)\Big)^{-1}$
now invert